# Using Java string.indexOf() to return different substrings-- possible?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am trying to build a simple interpreter. Basically I am using this method to obtain the keys to my `HashMap` from the Strings in an `ArrayList`. There are 8 different possibilities (8 keywords) that a string in the `HashMap` can start with. Currently I'm using `string.indexOf("something")` to find the keyword string, but of course this isn't at all flexible once I have more than one keyword.

All the Strings in the `ArrayList` can be broken up into COMMAND+ (INSTRUCTIONS). The COMMANDS map to the  `HashMap` and its classes. So basically it's a 2 step situation: the first time through I need to get the first word/token from the String, and then the rest of the string preferably to be further split/tokenized in the appropriate class.

Is there anyway `string.indexOf()` can be somehow manipulated to return the indices of more than one sub-string? Or do I have to look elsewhere for some other method? Please advise.

Code looks like this:

```
public void parseCommands() {
    List<String> myString = new ArrayList<String>();
    myString.add(new String("# A TPL HELLO WORLD PROGRAM"));
    myString.add(new String("# xxx"));
    myString.add(new String("STRING myString"));
    //myString.add(new String("LET myString= \"HELLO WORLD\""));
    //myString.add(new String("PRINTLN myString"));
    myString.add(new String("PRINTLN HELLO WORLD"));
    myString.add(new String("END"));

    System.out.println();
    for (String listString : myString)//iterate across arraylist
    {
        if (listString.startsWith("#", 0))//ignore comments starting with #
        {
            continue;
        }

        int firstToken = listString.indexOf("END");
        String command = listString;


        Directive directive = commandHash.get(command);
        if (directive != null) {
            directive.execute(listString);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No mapped command given");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` can't be manipulated to return anything other than what it already returns. Without knowing what your input strings look like, it's impossible to help--would a simple `split()` suffice?

Comment: You might want to read about the RegEx capabilities of Java ... Needs ab bit of reading, try and error and effort, but surely does the job.

Comment: You don't seem to use `firstToken`. You explanation is not clear enough to reflect the requirement.

Comment: So, "END" key in the HashMap? And also is also is the keys to the map limited to 8? If yes why are you not using those?

Comment: Also it's a bad practice to do `new String("")`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like each string in the AL could either be just a command or command and input for the command.

I think you can use the `split` method here:

```
String[] parts = listString.split(" ");
```

If the size of `parts` is one that means it's just a command, otherwise `parts[0]` is a command and the rest, input for that command.

Do the lookup with it:

```
Directive directive = commandHash.get(parts[0]);
```

Then if a `Directive` is returned then

1. If `parts`'s length is 1 then just do `directive.execute()`.
2. Otherwise, form the input with the rest of the `parts` and do `directive.execute(input)`.

If that is not the case, maybe I didn't get what you are trying to say.

Also, see [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), it has all sort of method that you can utilize here.

**Update:**

```
public interface Directive {    
    void execute(String input);
}

public class EndDirective implements Directive {
    @Override
    public void execute(String input) {
        // input will be neglected here
        // just do whatever you supposed to do
    }    
}

public class PrintlnDirective implements Directive {
    @Override
    public void execute(String input) {
        // input will be used here        
        // you might want to check if the input is null here
        // and write the code accordingly
        System.out.println(input);
    }    
}
```

With that you can do `directive.execute(null);` when you don't have any input because you the respective `Directive` either ignores the input or uses it (might also handle the null if they receive null when they are expecting some input).

Comment: @βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ thanks-- you have it right. The Strings in the AL are all decomposable to command+input, or command (only in the case of the END statement). If I use the `split()` method to get an array with 2 parts at 0 and 1 (`parts[0]`,`parts[1]`)-- my interface Directive only has this method `public void execute (String listString)`; do I need to add another method in there for `directive.execute(input)`? Thanks!

Comment: Yes add (overloaded) `directive.execute()` that does not take any parameter and you will be fine. Or you can also change the existing one to handle null input.

Comment: @ βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ if I wanted to change the existing one to handle null input, what do I need to modify in the method? Sorry if it's a noob question, but I've only been programming in earnest and learning Java for less than 2 months-- so many things are new to me.

Comment: It would be good see what the method looks like. But use a if statement first to see if the input is null. `if(input == null) {/*for no input*/} else { /* for command with input */ }`. And `directive.execute(null)`.

Comment: @ βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ The interface looks like this, there's only one method in there. 

`public interface Directive //Map keywords to an interface
 {
  public void execute (String listString);
 
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.  You probably want to use String.split(), a StreamTokenizer, or a StringTokenizer.